# Can an employee be expected to find cover for herself when off sick?

Tags: united-kingdom, legal, sickness

A friend has been told that, if she is off sick, she needs to find someone to cover her shifts, and that she can't expect her manager to do that for her.

She is a part-time paid employee of a charitable organization. The charity runs sessions that can be attended by the public. Part of my friend's role is to ensure that there are sufficient volunteers to staff each session. Normally, my friend is present at these sessions herself, but if she is off sick, someone needs to 'phone around and find someone to come in and undertake her normal duties (setting out apparatus, overseeing the session etc.).

Her manager insists that this is not his responsibility to find cover when she is off sick, and that she has to do this herself.

Is this situation acceptable / legal in the UK? If not, what legislation covers this?

Comment: Sorry, but it's a legal question specific to UK. You are not asking in the right place.

Comment: @FrançoisGautier Questions of a general legal nature that are properly scoped (i.e. country-specific) are typically on-topic here. Anything that doesn't require analysis of a specific situation to what could constitute legal advice is normally fine.

Comment: I live and work in the UK and have never heard of this.  It's generally the employers responsibility to ensure they have adequate resources, this includes taking sickness into consideration. I  I would suggest your friend makes an appointment with the Citizens Advice Bureau to discuss this in further detail.

Comment: *Her manager insists that this is not his responsibility*, Well a manager can insist that his role is not to manage, he's still the manager...

Comment: @Lilienthal, 
I'm just refering to:
http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
What questions are off topic here?

    Questions asking for advice on what to do (including reviewing resumes, CVs, cover letters, e-mails, asking for legal advice, as well as specific salaries, billing rates, market worth, etc.)
He asked: 3 questions: 

1 - Is this situation acceptable in the UK? -> Opinion based
2 - Is this situation legal in the UK? -> answerable by a lawyer
3 - If not, what legislation covers this? -> answerable by a lawyer

Probably we could talk about it in the meta

Comment: @FrançoisGautier There have been a few discussions about this on [meta] with the main one being [here](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2423/what-criteria-do-we-need-for-questions-regarding-the-law-regulations-to-be-allow?noredirect=1). Monica's central answer there is our go-to. In practice this is usually taken to mean that a general question that an HR manager or business owner should be able to answer is something that's on-topic here. You can make a meta thread or find me in [chat] if you want to discuss it further since it would take us off-topic here.

Comment: This is a question that an HR professional should be able to give without requiring a lawyer/barrister or an actual legal opinion. Voting to reopen.

Comment: My personal response would be "I'm calling in sick, which means I am too sick to work - that sounds like work" and if they pushed it then I would lodge a complaint with an employment tribunal.

Comment: I'd ignore the "legal" part in the last sentence. The question is what the friend should do.

Comment: @Moo - if the job requires working with people in public, there are many illnesses that would be prudent not to be physically present especially if you think you're contagious, but you could still make a lot of phone calls from home.

Comment: @JeffO the employer doesnt get to make that determination in the UK - if you call in sick and dont voluntarily make the offer to work remotely, the employer cannot force you.  So my point stands.

Comment: So what exactly does her manager expect her to do if she has a bad laryngitis and lost her voice or is in bed with high fever? Call around to find cover for her shift? I cannot even remotely understand how a sick employee can have any other responsibility than calling in sick and getting better. No manager can determine if the employee is fine enough to do anything.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> A friend has been told that, if she is off sick, she needs to find someone to cover her shifts [...] What legislation covers this?

Nothing, apart from the fact that [slavery has been illegal since 1833](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slavery_Abolition_Act_1833.). To the best of my knowledge, **UK employment law does not specify the limits of what an employer can require of employees calling in sick but they can't stop employees from taking sick leave.** If the employer retaliates against an employee for not respecting an unreasonable policy like this then the employee will most likely be able to submit a successful claim with the employment tribunal.

Looking at in depth, the only statutory regulations covering sick leave are those surrounding Statutory Sick Pay (SSP). There [GOV.UK does say](https://www.gov.uk/employers-sick-pay/notice-and-fit-notes):

> The employee should tell you they’re sick within your own time limit (or 7 days if you don’t have one). You can’t insist they tell you in person or on a special form.
>
> You don’t have to pay Statutory Sick Pay (SSP) for any days the employee was late in telling you (unless there’s a good reason for the delay).

But that doesn't really cover the fact that your employer has an understandable expectation that you'll inform him if you can't make it to work.

In this case I'll fall back to [ACAS](http://www.acas.org.uk) as a reputable source. On [managing short-term sickness they state](http://www.acas.org.uk/index.aspx?articleid=4201):

> Most ailments last only a day or so - some a week or two. But they are short-term illnesses - and this is what your employee should do if they are not coming in.
>
> - Speak to you or their manager as soon as possible. Many employers specify that within an hour of the employee's normal start time they must be notified of:
>
>   - the nature of the illness
>   - a likely return date.
> - If the illness lasts less than seven days, provide a self-certificate.
> - If the illness lasts seven days or more, provide a Statement of Fitness for Work (or Fit Note) from their GP.

ACAS also mentions the "legal right to be absent" and illness is one of [many qualifying reasons](http://www.employmentlaws.co.uk/guide/absence_from_work.html).

Given the absence of specific legislation, **an employee has to fall back to what's in their contract** Companies typically have policies covering sick leave and absences in general. Whether those policies are themselves legal if they risk violating employees' basic rights or can be grounds for a case of "constructive dismissal" is a more complex issue and will typically involve talking to ACAS,  Citizens Advice, or an employment lawyer.

So let's say an employer sets up a policy where people who don't arrange cover when they're sick have this counted against them as an unauthorized absence. The employer could refuse to pay the employee or could dismiss them, at which point the employee will likely have grounds to [submit a claim to the employment tribunal.](https://www.gov.uk/employment-tribunals/when-you-can-claim). Before that, ACAS (and potentially Citizens Advice) should be called upon to intervene and to try to mediate the dispute. At that point it becomes a matter for a legal expert, though it is my layman's opinion that a policy like this is clearly unfair and ludicrous and any action taken against an employee for not respecting the policy is equally unfair and will lead to a successful claim.

---

#### What now?

So now that we have all that out of the way, what could your friend do in this a situation? I would just tell her to explain to her manager that if she's too sick to work she's also too sick to arrange cover for her shift and that that responsibility should rest with the manager. Since the manager has already displayed a stunning level of incompetence and ignorance of his responsibilities I fully expect that this will not go over well. But I strongly suggest pushing back against this, ideally with multiple employees. If the company has an HR department or head office, they should be contacted next as they'd likely be livid if they heard of this.

---

<sup>I am not a lawyer and this does not constitute legal advice. This post is intended to summarise the available information on the topic of calling in sick and has been aggregated from what I believe are reputable source.</sup>

Comment: That's the obvious thing: Finding a replacement is work. If you're sick, you can't work, ergo you can't find a replacement. In other situations, like holiday, finding a replacement is work, therefore would have to be done in the time where you are paid for working.

Comment: There are a lot of illnesses that may prevent you from physically being at work or performing certain tasks for a long period of time, but you could take an hour to make some phone calls. If you have enough energy to call in sick, you can make an extra call or two.

Comment: @JeffO That's pretty damn heartless. And that thinking is precisely why so many people who *don't* have the energy to call in sick are still forced to do so to not risk their job. Even if we adopted that line of thinking you're also forgetting cases where people need others to call in sick on their behalf. Sick leave is intended to help people recover, not make them work from home. gnasher correctly pointed that this could be considered work out and that is itself a legal can of worms that my post doesn't even address.

Comment: @Lilienthal - If you have to contact someone to call in sick for you, why can't they call someone to cover for you? The point is, if you're sick, the manager isn't going to be able to do it.  Maybe the manager has too many people to take on this task for everyone?

Comment: @JeffO, the manager is presumably healthy. Yes she/he can take this on as her/his highest priority task when someone calls in sick and even be the replacement if needed. If it is not important enough for the manager to do that, then it isn't important to find a replacement.

Comment: @JeffO Hm. How would you react if an unknown guy called you on on the weekend from an unknown number and said "Hi, you don't know me but I'm <coworker>'s husband. She's sick today and you're her replacement. Go to <client's place> and organise the event there"?

Comment: @JeffO: Work is work. Your comment is effectively arguing that _a bit of work_ isn't really work and thus shouldn't be refused, which is massively subjective and crossing a line. For example, your boss can reasonably ask if you can call your replacement to give them a short explanation of the work that needs to be done. That's acceptable. However, if the sick employee is unable to do so, that should not bear negative consequences for them. Furthermore, failing to find a replacement should not preclude the ability to take a sick day. It is a _manager's_ job to manage the staff and workload.

Comment: @Flater - I agree that this is a bad practice for the manager to have this expectation, but that isn’t going to change for the OP. We don’t know the nature of the work or any legal implications. It sucks to take a day off of work and get roped into some task, but I cant claim I’ve never done a personal task while on the job. You get a little you give a little. Also I’ve been fortunate where I’ve never been so sick I couldn’t make a phone call or send an email. I’m no Superman; just fortunate.

Comment: @HGLEM - I know a bus boy who found someone to cover his shift and that person didn’t show up for work. Guess who got fired? Managers should do a lot of things, but they don’t have to. This is a bad practice, but I don’t see the OP being in a position to change it.

Comment: @Allthekingshorses - I admit that would be weird, but what are the options? Tell the manager to change his ways or get another job?

Comment: @JeffO In my book, it's clearly the manager's responsibility to *manage* the employees and their non-availability. Anything else will undercut security (because if employees are used to just about anybody calling and ordering them to do things just about anybody *can*) and the manager's standing. OP could start by making the point about security and then get advice about the legal situation from somewhere like https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're talking about the UK, there's one hot topic right now that would be extremely relevant to this: GDPR, which comes into force on 25th May.

In order to be able to arrange cover, it follows that you must have the personal contact details of the people who can cover for you. To do so when you're not at work, you need those contact details to be available to you at home. Since you mention that the manager doesn't consider this to be their job, then it further follows that all employees must be required to carry the personal contact details of anybody who can cover for them, in a format which allows them to access it at home.

GDPR imposes a number of requirements when it comes to handling employee data. Because the employee/employer relationship carries with it an inherent power imbalance, the employee's consent is generally not considered to be sufficient in its own right for processing the data. Broadly speaking, that means the employer must demonstrate a *legitimate interest* that justifies their holding that data. It's probably fairly reasonable for a company to need the personal phone numbers of its employees for the purposes of contacting them to cover shifts etc, so let's assume that's a given.

The next hurdle to clear is the question of *necessity*. Is the current approach a reasonable way of achieving this aim, and is there a less intrusive way to achieve the same goal? It seems to me that there's no reason for employees personal contact details to be available to other employees beyond their immediate manager and HR.

If the company can demonstrate that this method of processing employee's personal data is justified, proportionate and necessary, they need to:

- Ensure that the privacy policy applicable to employees specifies that their personal data will be held and processed by any coworkers who they are able to cover for
- Ensure that they have measures in place to control access to that personal data, and to be able to audit who has accessed that data and when.
- Ensure that the employee data held by other employees is secured such that it cannot be accessed by any unauthorised persons.

Of course, that's just the surface of the GDPR requirements - there's probably lots more. And that's before we get into the question of whether contacting other employees is in fact "working" - in which case the employee is entitled to be paid for their time, and would possibly be ineligible for statutory sick pay for that day.

Comment: Maybe I missed it, but how does this answer the question? You gave a really detailed explanation of GDPR and that is great, but ended with a statement that is just a *possibility* that they will be ineligible for pay (something not so reliable).

Comment: How does it not answer the question? The answer is **no, they cannot**, because it would require that the employee do something that is illegal, i.e. holding personal information without lawful basis and without an assessment of risk.